# Creating a dynamixel action client controller

Tags: ros, microcontroller, joints

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/Creatingdynamixelactionclient

When I run the command

```
python trajectory_client.py
```

Controller Manager shows following:

```
[ERROR] [1506614244.445647]: Incoming trajectory joints do not match the joints of the controller.
[ERROR] [1506614244.454837]: Excepcion in ypur execute callback: not all arguments converted during string formatting.
```

I have reviewed everything but did not find the error.

Thank you very much for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271763/creating-a-dynamixel-action-client-controller/) by [Montes](https://answers.ros.org/users/31916/montes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be a mismatch between joint names. In line 37 of the [dynamixel tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/Creatingdynamixelactionclient) : `arm = Joint('f_arm')` you need to set the same name as in your motor driver, i.e. `arm = Joint('joint0_position_controller')`

here I post a snippet of our arm driver based on [dynamixel_motor](https://github.com/socrob/dynamixel_motor).

```
  <node pkg="dynamixel_controllers" type="controller_spawner.py" name="joint_position_controller_spawner" output="screen"
        args="--manager=cyton_manager
              --port left_arm_port
              --type=simple
              joint0_position_controller" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2018-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Montes](https://answers.ros.org/users/31916/montes/) on 2018-03-19**:
Thanks you very much for your help.